# how to call the api initally to save the post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to save my snippet to the store. However I'm facing some issues now, I only get the snippet id from the server after I have done the api call. So the first time, I need to send only the snippetTile and snippetDescription to the api call. I want the snippetId to check whether a post already exist or not and to update it. How do I omit the snippetId in the api/savesnippets api call when I create a snippet for the first time? I want only the snippetTitle and snippetDescription to be send to the api call as I will get the snippetId as the server response if everything goes well. Right now my api call's request payload looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dfvu.png).

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-hooks-3bvg8)

actions.js where I call the api

```
import { SAVE_POST, UPDATE_POST, RETRIEVE_POST, HOME_LOADED } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
export const savePost = ({
  snippetId,
  snippetDescription,
  snippetTitle
}) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  let snippetData = { snippetId, snippetDescription, snippetTitle };
  try {
    if (snippetId == null) {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "/api/save",
        JSON.stringify(snippetData),
        config
      );
      snippetData.snippetId = res.data;  //cause I only get snippetId from the server
      dispatch({
        type: SAVE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    } else {
      await axios.post("/api/update", JSON.stringify(snippetData), config);
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

editor.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { savePost, retrievePost } from "./actions/posts";

class Editor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "",
      enteredText: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //Load the snippet
    retrievePost(this.props.match.params.snippetId);
  }

  // Save Snippet
  performSave = snippets => {
    console.log("save function clicked");
    const { enteredText, title } = this.state;
    this.props.savePost({
      snippetId: this.props.match.params.snippetId, //this should be null when initially I'm creating a new post
      snippetDescription: enteredText,
      snippetTitle: title
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="titletext"
          placeholder="Enter title here"
          limit-to="64"
          className="inptxt"
          onChange={title => this.setState({ title })}
        />
        <button className="btn savebtn" onClick={this.performSave}>
          Save Snippet
          <i className="fas fa-save" />
        </button>

        <textarea
          name="enteredText"
          onChange={enteredText => this.setState({ enteredText })}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  snippets: state.snippets
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { savePost, retrievePost }
)(Editor);
```

reducer.js

```
import {
  SAVE_POST,
  UPDATE_POST,
  RETRIEVE_POST,
  HOME_LOADED
} from "../actions/types";

import { initialState } from "../store";

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SAVE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippets: [payload, ...state.snippets] //this payload is only the snippetId right and not the actual snippet??
      };
    case UPDATE_POST:
      const newState = state.filter(
        post => post.snippetId !== payload.snippetId
      );
      return [...newState, payload];

    case RETRIEVE_POST:
      const newwState = state.filter(
        post => post.snippetId !== payload.snippetId
      );
      return [...newwState, payload];
    case HOME_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippets: payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import posts from "./reducers/posts";

export const initialState = {
  snippets: [
    {
      snippetId: "1",
      snippetTitle: "test",
      snippetDescription: "test test"
    },
    {
      snippetId: "2",
      snippetTitle: "post2",
      snippetDescription: "post 2 post2"
    }
  ]
};
const store = createStore(posts, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update **Action.js**

```
import { SAVE_POST, UPDATE_POST, RETRIEVE_POST, HOME_LOADED } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
export const savePost = ({
  snippetId,
  snippetDescription,
  snippetTitle
}) => async dispatch => {
const config = {
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
};

// remove snippetId here --------------------------------------
    let snippetData = { snippetDescription, snippetTitle };
// --------------------------------------

try {
 if (snippetId == null) {
  const res = await axios.post(
    "/api/save",
    JSON.stringify(snippetData),
    config
  );
  snippetData.snippetId = res.data;  //cause I only get snippetId from the server
  dispatch({
    type: SAVE_POST,
    payload: snippetData
  });
} else {

//add snippetId here for update use only --------------------------------------
  await axios.post("/api/update", JSON.stringify({...snippetData, snippetId}), config); 
// --------------------------------------
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_POST,
    payload: snippetData
  });
}
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks. also I need to send snippetId also as a payload to reducer or else in reducer, only snippetTitle, and snippetDescription will be saved right since I'm only sending snippetData as the payload and snippetId is not included there?

Comment: also `snippetData.snippetId =res.data` would be undefined. How do I assign the id that I'll receive from the server to the snippetId?

Comment: if `res.data` contains the id there's no reason that `snippetData.snippetId = res.data` returns undefined. double check your api response.

Comment: else you can do this 
`payload: {...snippetData, res.data}`

Comment: `payload: {...snippetData, res.data}` is fine. but in the reducer file, if you see the case `SAVE_POST` there, how do I store the entire post including snippetId, snippetTitle, snippetDescription within a single object in the snippets array? I'm just confused a little bit that's why I'm asking. please help me out bro

Comment: got what you need, well if the sniipets state is a array that contains the entire of your sinppets object that you are adding with post. then you should do this ... go down the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
// consider splitting your code with functions
const addToState = (state, action) => {
const cloneSnippets = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(state.snippets)) // for deep copy
cloneSnippets.push(action.payload) // payload contains all the snipets info (id, descrip.., )
  return {
    ...state,
    snippets : cloneSnippets
  }
}

case SAVE_POST:
   return addToState(state, action)
}`
```

Comment: where do I add the above portion of the code? in the reducer file? my codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-hooks-3bvg8 can you show exactly where you would put the above code?

Comment: also I have another problem is that after saving the post, I get the snippetId from the server which should be in the url immediately after first save like `http://localhost:8000/editor/123` or else if i click the save button again then it saves a duplicate copy with new id. however I don't want that. I want the url to be updated immediately so that when I click the save button again then it updates the post instead of adding a duplicate copy

Comment: if you want to handle the save and edit in the same form, you have to choices. the first one is to check if the current snippet has a `id`, if so then it's a update else its a post. the second method is to contrôle whether it's post or put using a state (ex : requestType = "edit" || "add")  . check  post.js in your codesandbox

Comment: yeah I wanted to go for the first method. I want to check if there is any id in the url which is why I used `match.params.snippetId` in the performSave function. both the SAVE_POST and UPDATE_POST cases are in the action file. however I'm not sure how to update the `match.params.snippetId` immeditately after saving the post for the first time and that is why if I click on the save button again then it saves another new post which is a duplicate copy instead of updating the already existing one.

Comment: I can't check any changes if you have made in the codesandbox because if you save changes then it becomes a new sandbox so if you made any changes and saved the changes then can you send me the link of the forked sandbox that you made

Comment: here is https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-mountain-nzi9o 

you don't have to get the id from the url, just use the id that of the snippet object. react router is good to help in navigation so user can know where he is. you use axios for sending request, so you can just add the id in the axios url to update the snnipet

Comment: thank you so much for helping bro. and about react router, are you talking about using history.push after the api request like this ```const res = await axios.post("/api/savesnippets", snippetData, config); history.push("http://localhost:8000/editor" + res.data);```

Comment: also you asked to make put and delete request but it should match with backend too right? the backend guy had used post method everywhere that's why I used post in the frontend too. or can I make get and put request in the frontend even though it's just post method in the backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211102/discussion-between-nassim-mesdour-and-henrydoe).